# Sharing global variables across modules best practice

Tags: python, variables, global

I have a variable that needs to be accessed in functions across several modules and will not be modified while it runs (Could be modified before code runs).  I see 2 ways of doing this.

I could declare a variable in the global namespace and pass as a function input parameter

main.py

```
from utils import multiply_by_parameter

if __name__ == "__main__":

    parameter = 5
    result = multiply_by_parameter(5, parameter)
```

utils.py

```
def multiply_by_parameter(x, parameter):
    return x * parameter
```

vs.

Creating a config.py that holds the "global" variable

main.py

```
from utils import multiply_by_parameter

if __name__ == "__main__":

    result = multiply_by_parameter(5)
```

utils.py

```
from config import parameter

def multiply_by_parameter(x):
    return x * parameter
```

config.py

```
parameter = 5
```

Is there one method that is preferred over the other?

Comment: It is preferred not to use global variables. OTOH, you say that this is a value which never changes. In that case, it is actually a constant. For a constant it is OK to be global, but it should be placed at the top of the file (not in `__main__`), and its name should be uppercase (e.g. `MAX_TIMEOUT = 7`) to make it clear that it is a constant and that it is not supposed to change.

Comment: The value of parameter may be altered (the last line) but the variable ... will not be modified (the first line)?

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi edited for claficiation.  The variable will not be modified while the code runs, but can be modified before it runs

Comment: @zvone Thanks!  Does it also apply if the variable is not a constant number but a constant variable?  (Constant list, constant dict etc...)

Comment: Then no. you make your choice based on each scenario.